# Gitlab Activity feed needs authentication

Tags: gitlab, rss, feed, atom-feed, rss-reader

I want to add die Gitlab Activity Feed to my rss reader (Liferea 1.13.7 on Ubuntu 22.04). I am using the Subscription URL with die feed specific Token in the URL. But Liferea is asking for authentication to access this feed. I don't want to use my actual credentials, so I tried using my personal feed token as my password, but I get an authentication error. I am quite suprised, that I need an authentication for this feed, because the URL already has a Token in it.

I checked, if this is not a Liferea specific problem. So I opened in the URL in my browser with an open Gitlab session. In this case I could download the .atom file. Without an open Gitlab session I get following message in the source view of this URL:

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

My Question is:

How can I use the Activity Feed without using my Gitlab credentials?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to your profile settings: https://gitlab.com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens

And there, copy the **Feed Token** and replace the token from the link with your own token from above:
`https://gitlab.com/group/project.atom?feed_token=XXX`